# asp.net mvc 5 - getting same file when uploading multiple files with same extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I keep getting same output files with diffrent name when uploading files with same extention,but works normal when uploading files with differnet extention,it's driving me crazy please help! here is my code for the controller.

**controller:**

```
  public ActionResult NewItem(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file)
        {

                            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
                            {
                                var msg_file = new Message_File();

                                msg_file.MessageId = model.ID;

                                string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
                                string filename = Request.Files[i].FileName;
                                string filetype = Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[i].FileName);
                                string filesavename = "files01_" +
                                DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");
                                msg_file.FileSavePath = filepath + filesavename + filetype;
                                msg_file.UploadTime = DateTime.Now;
                                msg_file.FileName = filename;
                                msg_file.FileSaveName = filesavename;
                                

                                Request.Files[i].SaveAs(filepath + "/" + filesavename + filetype);

                                db.Message_File.Add(msg_file);
                                db.SaveChanges();

                            }

                return RedirectToAction("index");
        }
```

it's supposed to upload multiple different files not same file multiple times!

Comment: what could cause this problem?